# Class constructor not initialized in emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

Why is the constructor not initialized if run through emscripten? The radius value is 0.
If you run it as a console application, it works.

html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>example</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

const importObject = {
    env: {
    },
    wasi_snapshot_preview1: {
        proc_exit: () => {},
    },
}

WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('./demo.wasm'), importObject).then((result) => {
    const moduleExports = result.instance.exports
    const val = moduleExports.getRadius()
    console.log(val)
})

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.cpp

```
#include "PixelsMath.cpp"
#ifndef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    #include <stdio.h>
#endif

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    #include <emscripten.h>
#endif

PixelsMath pixelsMath;

extern "C" {
    
    #ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
        EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
    #endif
    long getRadius() {
        return pixelsMath.radius;
    }
}

int main() {
    #ifndef __EMSCRIPTEN__
        printf("%d", pixelsMath.radius);
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

PixelsMath.cpp

This code is working. No constructor declared here. radius = 22

```
class PixelsMath
{
public:
    long radius = 22;
};
```

This code is not working. Here the constructor is declared. radius = 0

```
class PixelsMath
{
public:
    long radius;

    PixelsMath() :
        radius(2222)
    {

    }
};
```

Then I added the binding code. But this code doesn't work either.
This code is not working. radius = 0

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    #include <emscripten/bind.h>
#endif

class PixelsMath
{
public:
    long radius;

    PixelsMath() :
        radius(2222)
    {

    }
};

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(PixelsMathExample)
{
    emscripten::class_<PixelsMath>("PixelsMath")
        .constructor()
        .property("radius", &PixelsMath::radius)
        ;
}
#endif
```

I compile the project like this

1. emcc main.cpp -o demo.wasm
2. emcc main.cpp -o demo.wasm --bind

What am I doing wrong?